# OS X 10.10 (yosemite) PHP 5.5.14 - Is there any way to install png support without HomeBrew

Tags: php, osx-yosemite

As Yosemite's built-in PHP comes without PNG and FreeType support is there any way to install PNG support without using HomeBrew??

Comment: yes, there are several but none of them are any easier.

Comment: can you share one or two?

Comment: I already tried this one... http://wangqinhu.com/install-gd-on-mavericks/    but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Dude,

Take a look at vagrant, and just search the internet for the following:
- github: lamp vagrant
- virtualbox (for vagrant)
- customize provisioning file if needed
- vagrant up!

Then you have like a headless virtualbox linux apache php server as a sandbox, and you even can share a folder where you reside your public webfiles on a case sensitive partition. So you just use your favorite editor to edit your php scripts.

Study vagrant!

I.